# Как искать используя команду locate?

Tags: консоль, macos, shell

Я начал изучение интерфейса командной строки (на macOS). Вопрос о команде **locate**: У меня возникли трудности с указанием места поиска: он осуществляется по всему компьютеру, но почему-то не просматривает, например, директории "Загрузки", "Музыка". У меня возникло два вопроса:

- Если не задавать конкретно этой команде место поиска где она
  действительно его осуществляет (в корне или где-то в другом месте)?
- Как правильно задавать этой команде то место, где я хочу искать
  (например необходимо просмотреть только "Загрузки")?

Comment: насчет почему не просматривает и возможное решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887431/locate-command-cant-find-anything-inside-documents-folder-on-mac

Comment: А я правильно понимаю что эта команда осуществляет поиск по базе данных, которая была создана в момент "установки" этой команды? Если на момент создания этой базы данных файла не было на компьютере то и найти его она не может- нужно обновлять эту БД?

Comment: просто при наборе `locate` у меня на макоси 10.15.2 выдает `default database: `/var/db/locate.database' or $LOCATE_PATH`, но если ее нет, то нужно создать как указано например здесь http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: хотя нет, при попытке поиска файла у меня тоже выдает, что нужно создать базу, а про время создания файла надо проверить

Answer (score 2):

Если резюмировать информацию ([раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888077/3004003) и [два](https://ss64.com/osx/locate.html)), то получается следующее:

1. Встроенная утилита `locate` не ищет в Документах, однако индексирует публично доступные файлы, начиная с корня. В качестве решения можно установить `GNU locate` через `homebrew` либо использовать `mdfind -name` (которая использует базу Spotlight)
2. Для обновления базы `locate` для созданных недавно файлов можно ее обновить с помощью команды `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` либо `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`.
3. Можно указать место поиска в конкретной директории с вложенными директориями, например чтобы найти файл `/private/var/db/locate.database`, можно указать `/private/*/locate.database`

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, на моем МАКе папка Загрузки для пользователя "everyone" вообще закрыта а системные файлы оказались открыты для чтения. Кто так это придумал и какая в этом логика не понимаю. Но изменив права и обновив БД, все стало получаться.